# Change the default codepage from latin1 to utf8 on a linux machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, charset

How can I change the default codepage/charset on a linux system from latin1 to utf8?
I need to do this on two systems, one is running Ubuntu and the other Debian.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` and add your locale to the list of supported locales if it isn't there already, eg:

```
en_US UTF-8
```

Regenerate the supported locales on your machine:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Open `/etc/default/locale` and check if LANG and LANGUAGE are changed:

```
LANG="en_US"
LANGUAGE="en_US:UTF-8"
```

if they are not, you can manually update them now.

reboot.

Comment: good answer, john, thx.  do you know what package adds the /var/lib/locales stuff?  my recent Debian 5.0.3 install doesn't provide that, although an old Ubuntu 7.04 install did.

Comment: Debian's locale settings are in `/etc/locale.gen` I believe.

Comment: hmmm. that looks like the stuff i selected during the `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, it's probably generated there.  maybe the old Ubuntu install generated the /var/lib/locales stuff too, `dpkg -S` doesn't find an associated package.  the Debian install does use the `/etc/default/locale` file for selecting system default.

Answer (score 0):

If you also need to switch latin1 encoded filenames to utf-8, use `convmv` (`apt-get install convmv`):

```
convmv -f latin1 -t utf8 -r /path/to/files
```

This will only show what it would do. Add the `--no-test` option to actually do it.