# How to change the Linux Localization?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, localization

How to do change the Linux or ubuntu   Localization?  is there easy steps which I can convert Linux or ubuntu  English into Tami language localization operating system ? or is there any free available Tamil Linux or ubuntu ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu comes with Tamil.  Try @Iterrier's answer first.  It's the easy way.  This will change your locale to a supported one, if it's in the list.

If you're having problems, make sure `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` contains a line starting with `ta_IN`.

If it's missing, add ta_IN UTF-8 and run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

otherwise, continue:

In `/etc/default/locale`, change

- LANG="ta_IN"
- LANGUAGE="ta_IN:ta"

Honestly, I can't confirm if you should be using `ta_IN` or just `ta`, but just make this entry match what's in `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local`.

If it's not already on your system, you'll need the ttf-tamil-fonts package - it's in the universe or multiverse.

You'll also want to [change your keyboard settings](http://cutecomputer.wordpress.com/2006/10/03/howto-tamil-keyboard-on-ubuntu-606/) as well.   Also see The [Ubunutu Tamil team wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TamilTeam/).

Answer (score 5):

Have you check in :

```
System > Administration > Language Support ?
```

If there is your language, you can easily change it without re-install.

Answer (score 1):

[Mandriva](http://www2.mandriva.com/) comes with Tamil fonts already pre-installed. For other distributions you can [download the fonts](http://www.tamil.net/tscii/tools.html). for changing your locale, follow [this](https://superuser.com/questions/55224/change-the-default-codepage-from-latin1-to-utf8-on-a-linux-machine/55233#55233) answer.

There is also a user group called [tamilinix](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/tamilinix/) dedicated to this, you may want to check them out.